# How can I pass destructured elements one by one to scrollDown() function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, destructuring

> I want to pass aboutSection,servicesSection to scrollDown() method one by one so that when I click on About and Services in Navbar scrollDown() method runs and provide the desired functionality. But I am unable to find any technique to pass elements to scrollDown().
> I have tried techniques like just writing props in parameter and then maping it and passing it to scrollDown() but it didnot work. I have also tried to use navItems.map to get the data from data.js and pass it to scrollDown() but it still did not work. I can pass a single element separately like aboutSection or servicesSection but I want to pass them both one by one.

```
import React from "react";
import { navItems } from "../data";
import { FaBars, FaTimes, FaAngleUp } from "react-icons/fa";
import { useState,useEffect,useContext } from "react";
import { AppContext } from "./context";

export const NavBar = ({aboutSection,servicesSection}) => {
  const [isactive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);
  const {scrollDown}=useContext(AppContext);

  const openSideBar = () => {
    setIsActive(true);
  };

  const closeSideBar = () => {
    setIsActive(false);
  };

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const position = window.scrollY;
    setScrollPosition(position);
  };

  const goToTop = () => {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={
          scrollPosition > 500 ? "scroll-up-btn show" : "scroll-up-btn"
        }
      >
        <i>
          <FaAngleUp onClick={goToTop} />
        </i>
      </div>
      <nav className={scrollPosition > 20 ? "navbar sticky" : "navbar "} >
        <div className="max-width ">
          <div className="flex">
            <h1 className="logo">
              Portfo
              <span className={scrollPosition > 20 ? "span-white" : "span"}>
                lio.
              </span>
            </h1>
            <ul className={isactive ? "menu active" : "menu"}>
              {navItems.map((item) => {
                const { id, url, text,funcName} = item;                
                return (
                  <li key={id} onClick={()=>scrollDown()} >
                    <a>{text}</a>
                  </li>
                );
              })}
              
            </ul>
            <div className="menu-btn">
              {isactive ? (
                <FaTimes onClick={closeSideBar} />
              ) : (
                <FaBars onClick={openSideBar} />
              )}
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: What is the desired functionallity? What arguments does the `scrollDown` accept?

Comment: const scrollDown = (ref) => {
        window.scrollTo({
          top: ref.current.offsetTop,
          behavior: 'smooth',
        });
        console.log("Scroll down is working")
      };